# Soldering 12 gauge wire to protoboard

Tags: soldering, breadboard

I would like to know if there is a way to solder this 12 gauge wire to my protoboard.

The wire is connected to a 12 V power supply so I need to find a way to connect it to my protoboard. The hole is small on the board and the wire is pretty thick. Is there maybe a connector to solder this?

[image]

Comment: Solder a piece of wire of the correct gauge for your protoboard onto the wire in the photo and sleeve it with heatshrink or tape. It's the wrong wire for the board.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Or lay it flat from the edge of the board and solder it onto the surface. The wire doesn't need to pass through the hole for it to be attached. I agree with transistor though, there probably isn't a good reason to do this.

Comment: what is connected at the other end of the 12 gauge wire?

Comment: Seconding @Transistor, except use heatshrink, not tape. Electrical tape is pretty awful stuff.

Comment: @jsotola It's a 12 V power supply. I need to also ground the circuit board cuz there's alot of current so I need a bigger gauge wire

Comment: Are you sure your pcb can support the current?

Comment: Why are you using solid core wire?  Stranded would be a lot nicer if you need to attach it to a board.  As others have noted, make sure your PCB can support the current.  No sense having 12AWG wire going onto a pad with a 20 mil trace...

Answer (score 12):

This is a case of the tail wagging the dog.
I would support the heavy wire with some loops of smaller gauge wire that are soldered to your protoboard (see photo). This will prevent the heavy wire from fracturing the solder joint or tearing the pads from the board.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

An appropriately sized screw terminal block can be used. 0.2" spacing between terminals make it ideal for prototype boards with 0.1" standard spacing.  Make sure it accepts 12 AWG solid wire.

[image]

Comment: 0.2" is much more common. no way can you fit that thick wire into a 0.1" terminal, if they even exist

Comment: @toblat updated

Comment: Or use a terminal with removable wire part so that the wire can be easily removed from the board. Handy when soldering if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

You could solder a solder/terminal pin or two into holes the PCB then solder your wire to that -
[image]

This terminal pin was copied from this [site](https://verotl.com/pcb-pins/pins/18-1660-single-sided-terminal-pin-with-barbed-pressfit-retention-for-1-02-dia-holes).

Comment: You'll likely get a hot mess (literally!!) when the pin unsolders from the board as you try to solder the wire to it.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I always use these pins when soldering wires to PCBs.  I have never had a problem.  The pin is barbed and is a press fit into the hole.